# Changing a div's class while hiding the other depending on if button is clicked 1st time or 2nd time

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I have a page where i use google maps api to display map on the right span(span9) and some info on the left span(span3).

What I want to do is, if user clicks button on the top, left span (span3) to slide toggle left and change map's class from span9 to span 12. (whole page). And if user clicks button again, vice veraa.(goes back to initial state)

How to do this using jQuery or prototype.js?

Here's the code :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <button id="bttn">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" id="statistics">
        <div id="gmapmenu">
            <form action="#" class="horizontal-form">
                <?include "map.toolbar.renderer.php"?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="map">
    <?php
        include "google.map.renderer.php";
        include "map.loading.renderer.php";
        include "map.detail.graphics.renderer.php";
        include "map.legend.renderer.php"
    ?>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: fist click -> get rid of

```
<div id="statistics" class="span3">
```

and change

```
<div class="span9" id="map">
```

to

```
<div class="span12" id="map">
```

EDIT 3: I add class which has margin-left:2px; and that solves the overflow issue

```
jQuery("#bttn").on("click", function () {
jQuery("#statistics").toggle("slow");
jQuery("#map").toggleClass("span12 span9");
jQuery("#map").addClass("emre");
```

});

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of"... do you want to hide it or delete the element and everything within '<div id="statistics" class="span3">'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the `<button>` you want to hide the stats and change `span9` to `span12`...
and when you click the `<button>` again, you show the stats again and revert the `span12` to `span9`, you can achieve this with **jQuery** easily; you can [experiment with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD5m6/) I made you as well:

```
$("#bttn").on("click", function () {
    $("#statistics").toggle();
    $("#map").toggleClass( "span12 span9" );
});
```

Comment: That helped but, if you can see my edit, it overflows

Comment: Is there any way you can adjust the map setting so that you display it by % and not pixel value? That way you can have the map span 100% of the document.

If not, you can create a class that is styled overflow:hidden

Comment: Ok i got it working. see edit 3 please and thank you

Comment: You might want to add it in the stylesheet or use toggleClass instead of addClass, otherwise if you use the container for something else in the future, you would be stuck with that class.  Glad to see it works for you though :-)